# Assign value to row based on another sheet in Excel using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have two sheets within my spreadsheet. Sheet 1 has 5 columns: Item; Total Qty; Test Phase 1 Qty; Test Phase 2 Qty; Test Phase 3 Qty. Sheet 2 has two columns: Item; Test Phase.

I would like to create a macro to assign each item (every row) in Sheet 2 a test phase based on Test Phase qualities for that particular item in Sheet 1.

Sheet 1

| **Item** | **Total Qty** | **Test Phase 1 Qty** | **Test Phase 2 Qty** | **Test Phase 3 Qty** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Clock | 5 | 1 | 1 | 1 |

Sheet 2 - This sheet will have 5 rows for the Clock but we are only testing 3 of the total qty (Test Phase 1 - 3) therefore the Test Phase column for 2 of the rows should be left blank.

| **Item** | **Test Phase** |
| --- | --- |
| Clock | Test Phase 1 |
| Clock | Test Phase 2 |
| Clock | Test Phase 3 |
| Clock |  |
| Clock |  |

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please post your code and show us what is not working.

Comment: Welcome user23548324! Read [The Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and earn your first badge!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Use Dictionary object to transform data

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [Dictionary object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dictionary-object?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)

> [Range.CurrentRegion property (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.currentregion?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm144111)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

> [Range.Resize property (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.resize?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm144187)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Demo()
    Dim objDic1 As Object, objDic2 As Object, rngData As Range
    Dim i As Long, sKey, iStart As Long, iEnd As Long, iR As Long
    Dim arrData1, arrData2, bFull As Boolean, j As Long
    Dim oSht1 As Worksheet, oSht2 As Worksheet
    Set oSht1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set oSht2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
    Set objDic1 = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    Set objDic2 = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    ' Load test phase table into Dict
    arrData1 = oSht1.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value
    For i = LBound(arrData1) + 1 To UBound(arrData1)
        objDic1(arrData1(i, 1)) = i
    Next i    '
    ' Load item table into Dict
    With oSht2.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
        .Sort key1:=.Columns(1), Header:=xlYes
        Set rngData = .Resize(.Rows.Count + 1)
    End With
    arrData2 = rngData.Value
    sKey = arrData2(2, 1)
    iStart = objDic1(sKey)
    ' Store data size of each item
    For i = LBound(arrData2) + 1 To UBound(arrData2)
        If arrData2(i, 1) = sKey Then
            iEnd = i
        Else
            objDic2(sKey) = Array(iStart, iEnd)
            sKey = arrData2(i, 1)
            iStart = i: iEnd = i
        End If
    Next i
    ' Loop through each item
    For Each sKey In objDic2
        bFull = False
        If objDic1.Exists(sKey) Then
            iStart = objDic2(sKey)(0)
            iEnd = objDic2(sKey)(1)
            iR = objDic1(sKey)
            ' Populate Test Phase
            For i = 3 To UBound(arrData1, 2)
                For j = 1 To arrData1(iR, i)
                    arrData2(iStart, 2) = Left(arrData1(1, i), Len(arrData1(1, i)) - 4)
                    If iStart = iEnd Then
                        bFull = True
                        Exit For
                    Else
                        iStart = iStart + 1
                    End If
                Next
                If bFull Then Exit For
            Next
            If Not bFull Then
                For i = iStart To iEnd
                    arrData2(iStart, 2) = ""
                Next
            End If
        End If
    Next
    ' Write output to sheet2
    rngData.Value = arrData2
End Sub
```

[image]